# Como redondear el resultado de una operación en c#

Tags: c#

Mi pregunta básicamente es esa, como redondear el resultado de una operación.

```
Double Q = 7;

Double D = 4

t = Q / D;

Console.Write("t = " + t);
```

`Math.Ceiling` y `Math.Round` no me están ayudando en este caso.

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Puedes ser más claro? `Math.Round` redondea el resultado. ¿Por qué dices que no funciona?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no entiendo exactamente por qué no puedes usar el math.Round, este es un método manual para hacerlo en este caso a dejarlo sin decimales:

```
 Double Q = 7;

        Double D = 4;

       Double t = Q / D;
        Double a =t- Convert.ToInt32(t);//cogemos los decimales
        Console.WriteLine("t = " + t);

        t= Convert.toInt32(t)+ (a * 10 >= 5 ? 1 : 0); //si es mayor  o igual que 5 se suma 1 sino 0

        Console.WriteLine("t = " + t);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero simplifica el "Double", Crea la variable t como double,   convirtela en int, luego ponle el Round.

**Mira**

```
        double t;
        double Q = 7;
        double D = 4;
        t = Q / D;
        Console.Write("t = " + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(t)));
        Console.Read();
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Salu2**

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer directo en la operación con Math.Round(Núm a Redondear,Cantidad Décimales), si le pones Cero a como lo hice, te lo redondeará al entero mas cercano. Espero te sirva:

```
   double Q = 7;
   double D = 4;
   double T = Math.Round((Q / D),0);
   Console.Write("t = " + T);
   Console.Read();
```